# Android Emulator wont work in debug mode

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, haxm

Android emulator will just not work when trying to debug the app as it just shows a blank black screen.

When I run the app, it displays the application screen, however, once I try to debug the application it just shows a blank screen while the emulator is in debug mode.

Please can you advise or help ?

```
emulator: device fd:796
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
emulator: device fd:796
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just taking a long time? The emulator can be significantly slower in debug mode.

Comment: No it been like that since 30 minutes now

Comment: console shows that debugger has launched, but its a blank black screen.